# Looking for clarification on the end of this Ruby Challenge - Bowling Ascii art

Tags: ruby, ascii, ascii-art

```
y=(1..10).map{|i| i.to_s==$*[0]?($*.shift;?0):?.}
4.times{|i| puts (y.pop(4-i)* ' ').center 8 }
```

output:

```
. . . .
 . . .
  . .
   .
```

What is the `* ' '` doing inside of the parens

Comment: You could have just me asked on PPCG! ;)

Comment: I was about to mention [this answer](http://quia.cf/orange/pooxy4/nph-poxy.pl/es/20/http/codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42645/draw-a-bowling-formation) (I guess I just did) and ask @britishtea to provide an explanation.  The answer seems to be for a more general case, however. For just the dot-picture it would simplify quite a bit.

Comment: Nobody seems to have mentioned that `$*` is a global variable holding command-line arguments.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a readable version of the code that should clarify things :)

Comment: whats with the cryptic formatting?

Comment: @maxpleaner it's a codegolf challenge. The objective is to write your code as concise as possible.

Comment: @britishtea yeah, i eventually noticed. pretty wierd stuff.

Comment: Please format your code properly. That is a horrible, unreadable mess.

Comment: @Jörg, while not an excuse, the code was lifted from [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), where horrible, unreadable messes are the norm.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I know, but this isn't PPCG, it's SO, isn't it? As an experiment, I just ran the code through an automatic formatter. That alone is almost sufficient so that the answer becomes self-evident: `y` is the result of a call to `map`, ergo it must be an array. `Array#*` is well documented. Just introducing a little whitespace will make that easy to spot.

Answer (score 1):

After the first line, `y` is an array of strings like this:

```
y=(1..10).map{|i| i.to_s==$*[0]?($*.shift;?0):?.}
# => [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."]
```

[`Array#*str`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-2A) is equivalent to [`Array#join(str)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join), it concatenate the strings together. In particular, `* ' '` concatenate the strings in the array with a whitespace:

```
y.pop(3)
# => [".", ".", "."]
y.pop(3) * ' '
# => ". . ."
```